# Realm Xamarin - Error on GetInstance()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, realm

I set my main page in this way:

```
namespace MyNamepage
{
public partial class MyPage: ContentPage
  {
    private Realm realm;
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    }
  }
}
```

Debugging the Android project i got this error and the app crash:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.

- I've installed "Realm" in PCL and in Droid Project using NuGet but it seems doesn't work.
- If i remove the GetInstance() call, the app doesn't crash;

Stack trace:

```
10-17 10:36:31.935 I/MonoDroid(31518): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Realms.RealmPCLHelpers.ThrowProxyShouldNeverBeUsed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at MyPack.SidePage.MyPage..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyPack\MyPack\MyPack\SidePage\MyPage.xaml.cs:14
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
10-17 10:36:31.955 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:644
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:650
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (Boolean nonPublic) [0x000ca] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:115
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:89
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5599
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at MyPack.MainPage.OnItemSelected (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) [0x00016] in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyPack\MyPack\MyPack\MainPage.xaml.cs:24
10-17 10:36:31.965 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs)
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.OnSelectedItemChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x0001c] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent) [0x0010e] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0014b] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, SetValueFlags attributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.NotifyRowTapped (Int32 groupIndex, Int32 inGroupIndex, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell) [0x0004c] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.NotifyRowTapped (Int32 index, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell) [0x00023] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.HandleItemClick (Android.Widget.AdapterView parent, Android.Views.View view, Int32 position, Int64 id) [0x00056] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellAdapter.OnItemClick (Android.Widget.AdapterView parent, Android.Views.View view, Int32 position, Int64 id) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at Android.Widget.AdapterView+IOnItemClickListenerInvoker.n_OnItemClick_Landroid_widget_AdapterView_Landroid_view_View_IJ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_parent, IntPtr native_view, Int32 position, Int64 id) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:215
10-17 10:36:31.975 I/MonoDroid(31518):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:585983a8-79f2-48a3-ac33-5b4c905219f1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long)
10-17 10:36:31.995 D/Mono    (31518): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-17 10:36:31.995 D/Mono    (31518): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
10-17 10:36:31.995 D/Mono    (31518): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
10-17 10:36:31.995 D/Mono    (31518): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518): Unhandled Exception:
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at Realms.RealmPCLHelpers.ThrowProxyShouldNeverBeUsed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at MyPack.SidePage.MyPage..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyPack\MyPack\MyPack\SidePage\MyPage.xaml.cs:14
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:644
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:585983a8-79f2-48a3-ac33-5b4c905219f1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long)
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono    (31518):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:585983a8-79f2-48a3-ac33-5b4c905219f1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long)
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at Realms.RealmPCLHelpers.ThrowProxyShouldNeverBeUsed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at MyPack.SidePage.MyPage..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyPack\MyPack\MyPack\SidePage\MyPage.xaml.cs:14
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:644
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:585983a8-79f2-48a3-ac33-5b4c905219f1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long)
10-17 10:36:34.115 E/mono-rt (31518):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:585983a8-79f2-48a3-ac33-5b4c905219f1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long)
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: `10-16 17:27:52.792 D/Mono    (10277): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0x66958db8] -> System.Diagnostics.Debug[0x66a5e9c0]: 3
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Comment: @Cheesebaron any suggestions ?

Comment: There should be a lot more to that stack trace

Comment: `> 0x20 in Android.Widget.AdapterView.IOnItemClickListenerInvoker.n_OnItemClick_Landroid_widget_AdapterView_Landroid_view_View_IJ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:215,5 C#
` and  `0x1D in MyProject.MainPage.OnItemSelected at C:\Users\myuser\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\MainPage.xaml.cs:24,17 C#` ask me if you need other logs to help me

Comment: Just add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: @Cheesebaron i edited question, you mean this as "stack trace"?

Comment: No it will be in the output window.

Comment: Maybe it's because of https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#android-abi-support ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce no, i tried. but still not work

Comment: When you run your application and the exception is thrown, press continue until it crashes. The stack trace should be in the output window.

Comment: @Cheesebaron updated again

Comment: Looks like your Android project is referencing the wrong DLL file. Can you please check inside of the csproj what the path is to the Realm.dll?

Comment: @Cheesebaron `<Reference Include="Realm, Version=0.78.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Realm.0.78.1\lib\portable-net45+sl5+wp8+wpa81+win8+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS10+monotouch+Xamarin.Mac\Realm.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>` it seems right path

Comment: It is not the correct one...

Comment: @Cheesebaron the Droid csproj target the right path too `<Reference Include="Realm, Version=0.78.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Realm.0.78.1\lib\MonoAndroid44\Realm.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the stack trace indicates and the path you have posted in the comments shows. You have installed the PCL version into the platform specific projects. Which is why it throws the `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception you are getting.

Try reinstalling the NuGet in your platform specific projects. Alternatively you can manually change the reference to point at:

```
packages\Realm.0.78.1\lib\MonoAndroid44\Realm.dll
```

You shouldn't have any reference to the portable folder in your platform specific project.

Comment: The 1st path that i've added refer to PCL project directory csproj file, the 2nd one refer to Droid project directory csproj file.
I tried to reinstall Realm in the droid project but it still don't work.

Comment: In the Android csproj file, you should _only_ have a reference to what is in MonoAndroid44.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using **Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1008975** with **Realm 4.0.1**

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Realms.SharedRealmHandle' threw an exception.
>   occurred

The solution was to completely uninstall the nuget Realm package from all projects in the solution and reinstall Realm back again.  Also make sure that you have the **FodyWeaver.xml** file in all projects.